# Sql server block next join if previous one found anything

Tags: sql, sql-server

From techincal perspective I just want to block following join whenever previous join will find result.

From business perspective I have simple list of clients and prospects assgined to one policy.
I have functionality to list all prospects assigned to one policy with duplication status columns.

- client_duplication column is based on fact there is already client
  with similar data
- prospect_duplication column is based on fact there
  is already prospect with similar data

**The most important part is whenever there is client duplication I dont want to check prospect duplication.**

My idea was to make something like:

```
select p.*, client_duplication.status, prospect_duplication.status
from prospect p
cross apply (
   //find any first client duplication 
   select top 1
   case 
        when inner_prospect_uuid.id is not null then 'CLIENT_SAME_UUID'
        when inner_prospect_lastname.id is not null then 'CLIENT_SAME_LASTNAME'
        else null 
   end as status
   from prospect outer_prospect
   left join client inner_client on inner_client.lastname = outer_prospect.lastname
   left join prospect inner_prospect_uuid on inner_prospect_uuid.uuid = outer_prospect.uuid 
   left join prospect inner_prospect_lastname on inner_prospect_lastname.lastname = outer_prospect.lastname 
   where outer_prospect.id = p.id
) client_duplication 
cross apply (
   //find any first prospect duplication ONLY when client duplications is null
   select top 1 
   case 
        when inner_prospect_uuid.id is not null then 'PROSPECT_SAME_UUID'
        when inner_prospect_lastname.id is not null then 'PROSPECT_SAME_LASTNAME'
        else null 
   end as status
   from prospect outer_prospect
   left join prospect inner_prospect_lastname on inner_prospect_lastname.lastname = outer_prospect.lastname and inner_prospect_lastname.id != outer_prospect.id
   left join prospect inner_prospect_uuid on inner_prospect_uuid.uuid = outer_prospect.uuid and inner_prospect_uuid.id != outer_prospect.id
   where outer_prospect.id = p.id
) prospect_duplication
where p.policy_id = 123 
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

In such approach I see two problems:

1. I am calling always both cross applies
2. Second there is no better mechanism than cross apply ? I am afraid it will kill my application whenever there will be like milions of records in both tables

Comment: 2 ONLY applies if your filter is crap - if you can filter out from whatever table, then the cross apply will not be applied to millioons of entries. Filtering by a p.policy_id may be enough. If you are in doubt here, I suggest making a test query and posting the query plan. You may be surprised.

Comment: why do you want cross apply here?

Comment: @TomTom so you recommend to add inside cross aplies policy_id = '123' and thats all ?

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty I dont have any more ideas. For each prospect I call cross apply to find for each one duplications. This way was most intuitive for me.

Comment: Is your query returns the results? I see few errors, `inner_prospect_lastname` is not aliased for any of the table in the cross apply section of `client_duplication`

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty I've rewrote that from my production code, there are more conditons etc, so I've made simpler and more readable version. I've already fixed those things you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the join's that you are doing for the client and the prospect duplication. But instead of `CROSS APPLY` we can use `LEFT JOIN` as well

I really didn't understand the below join, with the below join you are again joining to the same record. `inner_prospect_uuid` and `outer_prospect` refer to the same record.

```
LEFT JOIN prospect inner_prospect_uuid ON inner_prospect_uuid.uuid = outer_prospect.uuid
```

---

Updated Query:

```
SELECT p.*
    ,COALESCE(client_duplication.STATUS, prospect_duplication.STATUS) [Status]
FROM prospect p
LEFT JOIN (
    --find any first client duplication 
    SELECT TOP 1 outer_prospect.id [Id]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN inner_prospect_uuid.id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 'CLIENT_SAME_UUID'
            WHEN inner_prospect_lastname.id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 'CLIENT_SAME_LASTNAME'
            ELSE NULL
            END AS STATUS
    FROM prospect outer_prospect
    --left join client inner_client on inner_client.lastname = outer_prospect.lastname
    LEFT JOIN prospect inner_prospect_uuid ON inner_prospect_uuid.uuid = outer_prospect.uuid
    LEFT JOIN prospect inner_prospect_lastname ON inner_prospect_lastname.lastname = outer_prospect.lastname
    WHERE outer_prospect.id = p.id
    ) client_duplication ON client_duplication.Id = p.Id
LEFT JOIN (
    --find any first prospect duplication ONLY when client duplications is null
    SELECT TOP 1 outer_prospect.id [Id]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN inner_prospect_uuid.id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 'PROSPECT_SAME_UUID'
            WHEN inner_prospect_lastname.id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 'PROSPECT_SAME_LASTNAME'
            ELSE NULL
            END AS STATUS
    FROM prospect outer_prospect
    LEFT JOIN prospect inner_prospect_lastname ON inner_prospect_lastname.lastname = outer_prospect.lastname
        AND inner_prospect_lastname.id != outer_prospect.id
    LEFT JOIN prospect inner_prospect_uuid ON inner_prospect_lastname.uuid = outer_prospect.uuid
        AND inner_prospect_uuid.id != outer_prospect.id
    WHERE outer_prospect.id = p.id
    ) prospect_duplication ON prospect_duplication.Id = p.Id
WHERE p.policy_id = 123 
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: uuid in this case is identity of person (Business id)

Comment: is it allowed to use p.id inside left join subselect ? - 'WHERE outer_prospect.id = p.id'.
coalesce will omit calling second join ?

Comment: we cannot skip joins based on condition. what ever the joins that you write in a query will get executed for sure, but we can modify the data that we need from the joins. The above query will not return the prospect status if it has client status

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution to this problem is always doing both joins, but using a `coalesce()` operator in the `SELECT` clause to prefer the first option, such that the second option only appears if the first didn't match anything.

Comment: but the question is do the db engine will omit second join when the coalesce will find first value or not ? I am looking for optimization and such solution dont sounds like avoding of calling second join